# Solidity modifiers and Aspect Oriented Programming

Tags: ethereum, solidity, aop

Can we say that modifiers in solidity follow the aspect-oriented programming paradigm?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not represent a programming problem and is fit more for a discussion forum than a Q/A site like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, modifiers follow the [decorator pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator).